# Getting and inserting values into multiple tables concurrently?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

The `number` column is also unique and the next number is determined by a stored procedure and get's the current number + 1 and saves it back to a common `numbers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tablename] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [currentnumber] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

The above system works fine when inserting single records. However, now I have a situation where I'm inserting records in batch and each inserted record must have a unique number determined by the stored procedure.

Currently, the only way I managed to get this working is by using a cursor which gets the next `n` numbers and stores them into a table variable, something similar to this:

```
declare @recordid int
declare @nextnumber int
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
select id from @records

open cur

fetch next from cur into @recordid

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    exec @nextnumber = get_nextnumber 'orders', @nextnumber output
    insert into @numbers VALUES (@recordid, @id_nextnumber);

    fetch next from cur into recordid
END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Afterwards, I join the `@numbers` table variable with the `@records` TVP and I insert records into the actual table.

Is there a better and cleaner way to do the above but avoiding cursors altogether?

The insert should be done using `MERGE INTO` because I need to use `OUTPUT` to capture some columns.

Comment: Why a numbers table and not a sequence?

Comment: The better and cleaner way would be to stop creating your own values for unique numbers like this. The way you have this built you have the potential for a race condition. Either use an identity or a sequence.

Comment: @SeanLange This a SQL Server 2000 db that's being migrated to 2016. Sequence looks like the way to go.

Comment: You already have a unique value, why adding another? Also, if you are upgrading, better upgrade to a later version, 2005 is no longer aupported by Microsoft.

Comment: Why not just use an identity? It looks you are using a unique set of numbers for each table anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange The `identity` column is used internally and not exposed to the client. The `number` column is exposed to the client. We have situations where the number can be supplied directly by the user or generated by the db. That's why we have 2 separate columns. In this batch insert situation, the number is generated by the db, therefore I'll use sequences.

Comment: OK. Seems a bit strange to have two different unique values per row in a table but whatever.